# How to split screen in TotalTerminal to end up with two terminals?

Tags: terminal

Often when you have `ssh`'ed into a server, you could like a second terminal to continue right off there, without having to `ssh` again.

I know that iTerm2 can do it, but it feels buggy on multi screens.

TotalTerminal makes a solid impression but seems to lack that feature, unless I have overlooked it.  Is there a way to split the terminal horizontally or vertically and have two independent terminals working off the same place?

Comment: This sounds like a feature request for Terminal. Please file a report at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/. You can use any Apple ID to access the developer site.

Answer (score 1):

The way I achieve this is ensuring that `tmux` is installed on the machine I'm SSHing to.

Once you've issues `tmux` you can do `ctrl-b %` to split the screen vertically, or `ctrl-b "` to split it horizontally.

This will give you two sessions within the same terminal window, and can also be persistent across logins. This may not be exactly what you want though.

Comment: And, starting in OS X 10.11 El Capitan, Terminal supports Mouse Reporting, so you can enable mouse support in `tmux` and use the mouse to resize and manipulate tmux panes.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning TotalTerminal—which doesn't have a split-pane feature—may be too specific. You just want to know if there's a solution for Terminal, right?

It would help if you elaborated on what you mean by “continue right off there” and “without having to `ssh` again.”

If you create a terminal using **Shell > New Remote Connection…** or **Shell > New Command…** to run `ssh`, Terminal’s **Shell > New Window/Tab with Same Command** commands can create a new terminal and run the same command within it automatically.